# How to set cookie in url in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, cookies

what i need

- i need to append the cookie data in url in jquery.

AcmeExtension.Php

```
    Public function get_hash_attend($event_id,$user_id)
    {
        echo  $event_id;
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $user_id;
        $key = '!@#hjka@#$jks*&@';
        $encrypt=$user_id."-".$event_id;
        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $xyz = (base64_encode($encrypted));
        $xyz = urlencode($xyz);
        $xyz = str_replace("%2F",")",$xyz);
        $xyz = str_replace("%3F","_",$xyz);
        $xyz = str_replace("%2B","(",$xyz);
        $hash='http://'.DOMAIN_NAME.'/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/'.$event_id.'/'.$user_id.'/'.$xyz.'?source=oneclickEmail';
        return $hash;
        //$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $d, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    }
```

js code

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $( "#attend" ).click(function() {
               alert( "attend  .click() ." );
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"{{get_hash_attend(9,13530767)}}", 
                     success: function(data)
                     {
                           alert(data);
                           $("#attend").text("Attending");
                           //alert(data);


                    }
                });
            });




        });

        </script>
```

problem im facing

- when i used url:"{{get_hash_attend(9,13530767)}}" works fine.
- but how to get cookie data as user is save in cookie.
- i  have $data[$k]['event_id'] in twig

[image]

I Need :

- i Need to fetch user data from cookie in function .
- id of particular url.

Comment: Do you want to read cookie value in jquery?

Comment: i have cookie set in browser how to get cookie and set in url

Comment: $.cookie('cookie name') will give you the value of cookie if you use the plugin suggested by @dtelaroli in answer.

Comment: i have tried $.cookie('user',user);

Comment: Please try $.cookie('user')

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: no im looking for another solution : <td width="50%" align="center" class="pd"><a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="btn btn-primary btn-listing" id="attend">Attend</a></td

Comment: im loooking for ajax xcall

Answer (score 0):

You can to use a jquery plugin to get/set cookie data directly with javascript.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme

Comment: is it possible without plugin